# Prevent text go on the picture on small width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 4 images with 4 text for each image. I located them in same row, but if i am reducing width of browser to check responsivity, text goes on the picture. I need to locate them in same row, prevenet text goes on the picture and if it is possible  from 4 columns make 2 columns if image with text does not fit. Here is mty code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-10 col-md-12">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img class="imgheight" src="https://texnoplus.az/image/icons/a2.png">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xs-12">
        <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Цены</b></span><br> Низкие цены<br> На все товары
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img class="imgheight" src="https://texnoplus.az/image/icons/a2.png">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xs-12">
        <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Цены</b></span><br> Низкие цены<br> На все товары
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img class="imgheight" src="https://texnoplus.az/image/icons/a2.png">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xs-12">
        <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Цены</b></span><br> Низкие цены<br> На все товары
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img class="imgheight" src="https://texnoplus.az/image/icons/a2.png">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xs-12">
        <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Цены</b></span><br> Низкие цены<br> На все товары
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img class="imgheight" src="https://texnoplus.az/image/icons/a2.png">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xs-12">
        <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Цены</b></span><br> Низкие цены<br> На все товары
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using text overflow css property, but the caveat is that, your text will be cut off and the overflow will be replaced with ellipses.

Comment: @ImmortalDude yeap, and I do not need my text be cut off, therefore can not use it. I need my text to be shown for any width

Comment: Then something has to give in, either your image has to become small in size or your text needs to word-wrap or you need to make the text and image on separate lines on small screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Added new class "**NEWCLASS**" for that div, and text does not go on the image.

```css
.NEWCLASS {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 105px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 NEWCLASS">
  <img class="imgheight" src="https://texnoplus.az/image/icons/a2.png">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xs-12">
    <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Цены</b></span><br> Низкие цены<br> На все товары
  </div>
</div>
```